# I want to be able to just list the lowest priced product sold for the day after i do a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to list the lowest priced product sold for the day after i do a query on microsoft server sql studio 2008.

This what the table looks like its name is SALES

DATE        PRODUCT_SOLD     PRICE

2013-11-15,   crab pot   ,     21.15

2013-11-15,   bait     ,        3.50

2013-11-15,   hooks    ,       11.99

2013-11-15 ,  sinkers    ,      1.99

2013-11-15 ,  fishing rod  ,   49.99

2013-11-16 ,  baitcaster  ,    29.99

2013-11-16 ,  squid bait   ,    3.50

2013-11-16 ,  knife  ,          9.95

2013-11-17 ,  fishing rod  ,    99.95

2013-11-17 ,  net     ,         25.99

How do I display it so it just list the lowest priced product for a day.

like this below.

2013-11-15 ,  sinkers    ,      1.99

2013-11-16 ,  squid bait   ,    3.50

2013-11-17 ,  net     ,         25.99

thx Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM sales t1
JOIN (
  SELECT date, min(price) price FROM sales
  GROUP BY date
) t2 ON t1.date = t2.date AND t1.price = t2.price
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5734/1).

Comment: Be aware that this will return multiple minimums if they exist

Comment: multiple minimums is ok

Comment: when i did out query on microsoft sql server mangament studio 2008 2013-11-15 00:00:00.000 sinkers 1
2013-11-16 00:00:00.000 squid bait 3
2013-11-17 00:00:00.000 net 25

Comment: The solution doesn't truncate anything at all. Maybe sql server management studio is not properly formatting the output. Maybe you will have to cast the price to `CAST(min(price) as numeric(6, 2))`?

Comment: im just a newbie  here

Comment: just a quick follow up question what if i only wanted to list the 2nd lowest price?

Comment: Hoho, that question has a **radically** different answer :) Ask that question as a new question and someone will give you the answer (if no one helps you then let me know and I can give you a hand with that :)

Comment: Mosty I asked the question here but as a beginner im a bit puzzled what to do, can you show my how you to do 2nd lowest like you did at sql fiddle for my first question. this is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390389/now-i-want-to-be-able-to-list-the-2nd-lowest-priced-product-sold-for-the-day

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DATE, PRODUCT_SOLD, MIN(PRICE) AS MINPRICE
FROM SALES
GROUP BY DATE, PRODUCT_SOLD
```

Comment: The issue is that if you group by both fields you won't have one different date per row but rather a different `(date, product_sold)` pair per row