# Now I want to be able to list the 2nd lowest priced product sold for the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to be able to list the 2nd lowest priced product sold for the day after i do queries on microsoft server sql studio 2008. (I know  how to list the lowest thx to the guys who answered that question Here, but what if i just want to list the 2nd lowest, 3rd, or 4th lowest, but let just focus on how to list the 2nd lowest

This what the table looks like its name is SALES

```
DATE PRODUCT_SOLD PRICE
2013-11-15, crab pot , 21.15
2013-11-15, bait , 3.50
2013-11-15, hooks , 11.99
2013-11-15 , sinkers , 1.99
2013-11-15 , fishing rod , 49.99
2013-11-16 , baitcaster , 29.99
2013-11-16 , squid bait , 3.50
2013-11-16 , knife , 9.95
2013-11-17 , fishing rod , 99.95
2013-11-17 , net , 25.99
```

How do I display it so it just list the 2nd lowest priced product for a day.

like this below.

```
2013-11-15, bait , 3.50
2013-11-16 , knife , 9.95
2013-11-17 , fishing rod , 99.95
```

Comment: this how the guys showed me how to just list the lowest for the day http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388890/i-want-to-be-able-to-just-list-the-lowest-priced-product-sold-for-the-day-after/20388954#20388954

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT date, product_sold, price
FROM (
  SELECT date, product_sold, price,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY price) rank
  FROM sales
) t
WHERE rank = 2
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d46e/1).

Note that if you have values `1`, `1` and `2` this will return `2`. If you would like to return the *second* `1` then use `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `DENSE_RANK`.

If you're looking for a generic solution that would in most DBMS then you can go for:

```
SELECT s2.date, min(s2.price) price FROM (
  SELECT date, min(price) price FROM sales
  GROUP BY date
) s1 JOIN sales s2 ON s1.date = s2.date AND s2.price > s1.price
GROUP BY s2.date
```

Note this one would work as the `DENSE_RANK` solution.

Comment: It is very unlikely that a solution works for all numbers but the 17th :) Create a Fiddle yourself that reproduces that behavior and then I'll see what the issue is (if any)

Answer (score 1):

You are unclear about what to do about ties.  Here is a solution using `dense_rank()`:

```
select date, product, price
from (select s.*, dense_rank() over (partition by date order by price ) as seqnum 
      from sales
     ) s
where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: thanks but this list the second highest not second lowest crab pot', 21.15 is second highest on the 15th

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I have changed the ordering from `DESC` to `ASC`, I hope you would agree with that.

Comment: @Kiril . . . Thank you for making that change.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
select blah, blah, min(price) second_lowest_price
from wherever
where price > (subquery to get lowest price)
group by blah, blah
```